# Quadratic variation of Stochastic Integral

Tags: stochastic-integrals, quadratic-variation

Let $B$ be a Brownian motion and $M_t = \int_0^t \mathbb{1}_{B_s=0} dB_s$. It can be shown that $(M_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a local martingale. Now, I want to calculate the quadratic variation of $M$.

In general, if $I_t = \int_0^t f(s) dB_s$ is an Itô-integral, then the quadratic variation of $I_t$ is
\begin{align}
\langle I \rangle_t = \int_0^t f^2(s) ds.
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
\langle M \rangle_t = \int_0^t \mathbb{1}_{B_s=0}^2 ds =  \int_0^t \mathbb{1}_{B_s=0} ds.
\end{align}
However, I do not see directly why $  \int_0^t \mathbb{1}_{B_s=0} ds = 0$?

Comment: That is the Lebesgue measure of the set of zero crossings of Brownian motion. If you google those terms you may find your answer.

Comment: You could evaluate the expectation of that integral using Fubini but that requires some argumentation.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\mathbb{P}(B_s=0)=0$ for all $s>0$, and therefore it follows directly from Tonelli's theorem that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t 1_{\{B_s=0\}} \, ds \right) = \int_0^t \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(1_{\{B_s=0\}})}_{=\mathbb{P}(B_s=0)} \, ds = 0.$$

Since the integrand is non-negative this implies

$$\int_0^t 1_{\{B_s=0\}} \, ds = 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$

Comment: Why is $P(B_s=0)=0$? $B_s$ is just a standard Brownian motion with $\mathbb{E}[B_s]=0$ isn't it.

Comment: @iJup $B_s$ is normally distributed for each $s>0$, so in particular $B_s$ has a density with respect to Lebesgue measure and this implies $\mathbb{P}(B_s=x)=0$ for any $x$.